# Asp.net mvc site project works on local machine, but some parts do not work after publishing

Tags: asp.net-membership

My Asp.Net MVC project works on local machine without any problems. And, in my project, I use membership provider.

After I publish my site, some parts work correctly. However, membership system does not work. And error message is "**Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.**"

My Connection String is like this;

```
 <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=111.111.111.111;Initial Catalog=DBname;Persist Security Info=True; User Id=123123;Password=pass;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="DATABASE" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model.csdl|res://*/Models.Model.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=111.111.111.111;Initial Catalog=DBname; User Id=123123;Password=pass;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

user login and register functions  , which uses "ApplicationServices", does not work.
But, other functions, which connect database with "DATABASE", works correctly.

Comment: >> local machine without any problems. - Cassini or IIS? There are dozens of threads on this problem, have you looked at published solutions (like you need to specify database=aspnetdb; in your connection string. Also, consider removing the asp.net-mvc tag. Deploy a Web Forms app and you'll get the same error. (IF you don't that's a big clue)

Comment: Thank you for your comments, local machine is ISS. I removed the MVC tag.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to allow the application to show you errors.

"Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request." is a default message.

In your web.config (Under system.web) add the following.

```
 <customErrors mode="off" />
```

Then report back with the error message you receive.

======= In Response to the Edit

The error is simply telling you that you havent imported one of the stored procedures. Make sure you've exported it from local (Via Generate Scripts or Backup).

Comment: Sorry :), meanwhile; in my local machine I use sqlserver 2008 r2; but my server is 2005. This can be export problem. New Error Message is:

Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.